# Getting variable in a loop from outside while 'function'

Tags: php, html

I have a while loop that assigns user ID's to a variable. The variable is an array. When I assign the variable to another in a link like this:  it returns proper ID's on the click but only when the link is in a while loop as well. How ( is it possible ) to place the link outside the while loop and get the same ID data the variable holds ?

This code works:

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { 
    $variable = $row['user_id'];
    echo "<a href='index.php?var=$variable'></a>";
}
```

This one doesn't in this case:

PHP:

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { 
    $variable[] .= $row['user_id'];
}
```

HTML:

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i <100 ; $i++ );
<a href='index.php?var=$variable[$i]'></a>
```

Thanks for comments..

Comment: You have to print the value inside the HTML, like so: `<a href='index.php?var=<?=$variable[$i]?>'></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { 
    $variable[] .= $row['user_id']; //Wrong
    $variable[] = $row['user_id']; //Correct
}

foreach($variable as $value) {
    echo "<a href='index.php?var=$value'></a>"; // Be sure to use double quotes
}
```

Comment: I'll try it out in a sec - yes I always use double quotes after echo / print - I didn't write them in my question...

Comment: Thanks ! Works... By the way you meant: index.php?var=$value ( not $val ) I guess...

Answer (score 5):

You've got a syntax goof:

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i <100 ; $i++ );
                              ^----
```

The semicolon terminates the for loop, so you're doing an empty loop. Change it to:

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i <100 ; $i++ )
    echo "<a href......etc....";
```

or better yet:

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i <100 ; $i++ ) {
    echo "<a href......etc....";
}
```

Comment: And also PHP does not evaluate simple quote strings '' only the double ones ""

Answer (score 0):

Several issues are coming into play here:

1. `$variable` is defined within the scope of the `while` loop, so it
   is inaccessible outside of said loop (though PHP may let you get away with this one).
2. You are assuming that there are precisely 100 rows (indexed 0-99) returned by performing the SQL query represented by `$sql`.  While this may be true, it's not good practice to assume this, and you should handle however many rows are *actually* returned by performing that query.
3. Perhaps most importantly, if you are truly using `<a href='index.php?var=$variable[$i]'></a>` in an HTML context, it will not work, as `$variable[$i]` is PHP code.  You will need to put this in a PHP document, somewhere between the `<?php` and `?>` tags.

Comment: #1 is outright false. php's variable scoping is at the function/method level. A var defined inside a while/for/if block is available outside the block as well.

Comment: Hey - of course I have all the html code within PHP ( to be concise I skipped the rest of it ) . I also have $i < $row_number; again, I wrote 100 to be more concise...

Comment: @MarcB Sure...they are available but strangely I managed to get ID loops in another program with the $variable outside the loop. In this case it fails...