# How to use variable from a while, but outside the while?

Tags: php, variables, while-loop

I have this:

```
$nome='x.png';
if(file_exists('../../images/produtos/'.$nome)){
       $i = 1;
       while(file_exists('../../images/produtos/'.$i."_".$nome))
    {
       $i++;
    }
        $nome = $i."_".$nome;
}
```

and then i need to put the variable $nome into a mysql_query, just like this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO produtos (nome) VALUES ('$nome)");
```

but it doesnt show the 'edited' variable.

Comment: Here is a good example showing how to take a variable from inside a while loop in PHP and pull it outside of the loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615618/getting-variable-in-a-loop-from-outside-while-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the answer to the [following Stackoverflow post by @PhpXp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615618/getting-variable-in-a-loop-from-outside-while-function), you could try to define the variable before the while loop. See below:

```
$report = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $report += "a"."b".$row["prevDOCid"]+1;
}
echo $report;
```